# Python os: [Errno 13] Permission Denied

Tags: python, path, permissions

I am trying to get a deep learning network (https://github.com/MIC-DKFZ/nnUNet) to work with my own dataset and I am having trouble with the paths. I have used several approaches to define my paths. The authors import the following packages for this issue:

`import os`

`from batchgenerators.utilities.file_and_folder_operations import maybe_mkdir_p, join`

With this, I have tried the following lines, separately:

`base = os.environ["nnUNet_base"]`

`base = join("Tortuosity", "nnUNet_base")`

`base = "Tortuosity/nnUNet_base"`

I have the `nnUNet_base` directory inside the `Tortuosity`directory. With the first approach it seems that it is not registering the directory correctly (I ask for `print("base =", base)` and in return I get `None`. For the second and third approaches, I obtain the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "experiment_planning/plan_and_preprocess_task.py", line 18, in <module>
    from nnunet.paths import base,splitted_4d_output_dir, cropped_output_dir, preprocessing_output_dir, raw_dataset_dir, network_training_output_dir
  File "/home/pere/anaconda3/envs/nnunet_env/nnUNet/nnunet/paths.py", line 51, in <module>
    maybe_mkdir_p(splitted_4d_output_dir)
  File "/home/pere/anaconda3/envs/nnunet_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/batchgenerators/utilities/file_and_folder_operations.py", line 40, in maybe_mkdir_p
    os.mkdir(os.path.join("/", *splits[:i+1]))
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/nnUNet_base'
```

I do not know how to habilitate permissions in this case. Please help, what should I do to effectively define the paths for my case? I am running a VM with Ubuntu 16.04 in a Mac.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says this:

```
os.mkdir(os.path.join("/", *splits[:i+1]))
```

That means, tht the path is under / and not in your home Directory. The fix that just use the absolute path at it is written in the comments of nunet.

```
base = "/home/pere/Tortuosity/nnUNet_base"
```

If Tortuosity is directly in your home folder.